User is not redirecting to the dashboard after the keycloak login with Nuxt V2.17.3 and Nuxt Auth V5
I'm currently working on a bit old project with Nuxt V2.17.2. I need to integrate the login flow with Keycloak V21.1.2. But after user logged In using Keycloak, Its not redirecting to the dashboard page which I prefer to go.
These are the related packages
"@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1667386184.dfbbb54",
"@nuxtjs/axios":"^5.13.6",
"nuxt": "^2.17.2",
This is my current nuxt.config.js file
 env: {
    tenant: "admin_sa",
  },
  /*
   ** Nuxt rendering mode
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode
   */
  ssr: true,
  /*
   ** Nuxt target
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-target
   */
  target: "server",
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head
   */

  plugins: [
    "~/plugins/loader.js",
    "~/plugins/notifier.js",
    "~/plugins/svg-icon",
    "~/plugins/axios",
    "~/plugins/vuetifyImageInput",
    "~/plugins/filter",
    "~/plugins/birthdayPicker",
    { src: "~plugins/vue-quill-editor", ssr: false },
  ],
  /*
   ** Auto import components
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-components
   */
  components: true,

  /*
   ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
   */
  buildModules: ["@nuxtjs/vuetify"],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next",
    // "bootstrap-vue/nuxt",
    "@nuxtjs/moment",
    "@nuxtjs/svg",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt",
    "vue-currency-filter/nuxt",
  ],
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: {
    baseURL: `${process.env.API_HOST}/api/bff/user-mgt`,
    // Used as fallback if no runtime config is provided
  },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    apiHost: process.env.API_HOST,
    realm: process.env.AUTH_REALM,
    clientId: process.env.AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    redirectURL: process.env.REDIRECT_URL2,
    logoutURL: `${process.env.API_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.AUTH_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=${process.env.API_HOST}`,
    userInfoURL: `${process.env.API_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.AUTH_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo`,
  },
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: false,
      keycloak: {
        // scheme: '~/plugins/keycloak.js',
        scheme: "oauth2",
        endpoints: {
          authorization: `${process.env.API_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.AUTH_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/auth`,
          token: `${process.env.API_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.AUTH_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token`,
          userInfo: `${process.env.API_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.AUTH_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo`,
          logout: {
            url:
              `${process.env.API_HOST}/auth/realms/${process.env.AUTH_REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=` +
              encodeURIComponent(String(process.env.REDIRECT_URL)),
            method: "get",
          },
        },
        token: {
          property: "access_token",
          type: "Bearer",
          name: "Authorization",
          maxAge: 1800,
          global: true,
        },
        // refreshToken: {
        //   property: "refresh_token",
        //   maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
        // },
        clientId: `${process.env.AUTH_CLIENT_ID}`,
        responseType: "code",
        grantType: "authorization_code",
        codeChallengeMethod: "S256",
        scope: ["openid", "profile", "email"],
        autoLogout: true,
      },
    },
    redirect: {
      login: "/login",
      logout: "/login",
      callback: "/callback",
      home: "/admin/dashboard",
    },
  },

  /*
   ** vuetify module configuration
   ** https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module
   */

  server: {
    port: 8080,
  },
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/
   */
  build: {
    babel: {
      compact: true,
    },
  },
  router: {
    middleware: ["auth"],
  },
  
};

This is my index.vue component
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: "home",
  created() {
    this.$router.replace("admin/dashboard");
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>


this is my login.vue component
<template>
  <div>
    <v-overlay opacity="0.1" :value="true">
      <div class="ma-5 pa-5 mt-10">
        <v-layout row wrap align-center>
          <v-flex class="text-xs-center">
            <v-row justify="center">
              <img class="home-logo" src="~static/images/bank.png" />
              <!-- <img class="home-logo" src="~static/images/logo-ekyc.png" /> -->
            </v-row>

            <loader-custom
              :loading="true"
              color="#3F5E9B"
              width="10px"
              height="40px"
            ></loader-custom>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </div>
    </v-overlay>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from "vuex";
import LoaderCustom from "vue-spinner/src/ScaleLoader.vue";
export default {
  layout: "home",
  components: {
    LoaderCustom,
  },

  async mounted() {
    this.$auth.loginWith("keycloak");
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.home-logo {
  width: 300px;
}
.login-btn {
  font-family: "CircularStd-Medium";
  margin-top: 10px !important;
  margin-bottom: auto !important;
  background: #3f5e9b !important;
  /* background: #6a6a6a !important; */
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px #e7eaf0 !important;
  border-radius: 12px !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  width: 250px !important;
  height: 46px !important;
  color: white !important;
}
</style>


This is my callback.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <v-overlay opacity="0.1" :value="true">
      <div class="ma-5 pa-5 mt-10">
        <v-layout row wrap align-center>
          <v-flex class="text-xs-center">
            <v-row justify="center">
              <img class="home-logo" src="~static/images/bank.png" />
              <!-- <img  class="home-logo" src="~static/images/logo-ekyc.png" /> -->
            </v-row>

            <loader-custom
              :loading="true"
              color="#3F5E9B"
              width="10px"
              height="40px"
            ></loader-custom>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </div>
    </v-overlay>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from "vuex";
import LoaderCustom from "vue-spinner/src/ScaleLoader.vue";
export default {
  layout: "home",
  // auth: false,
  components: {
    LoaderCustom,
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log("Callback", this.$auth.loggedIn);
    console.log("Callback", this.$store.state.auth.loggedIn);
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.home-logo {
  width: 300px;
}
</style>


this is my store/index.js file
export const state = () => ({
  allowedPermissions: [],
  loading: false,
  userId: null,
});

export const getters = {
  canBankMangement(state) {
    return state.allowedPermissions.includes(PERMISSIONS.CAN_BANK);
  },
  sectionConfigManagement(state) {
    return state.allowedPermissions.includes(PERMISSIONS.CAN_BANK);
  },
};

export const mutations = {
  SET_ALLOWED_PERMISSIONS(state, permissionsList) {
    state.allowedPermissions = permissionsList;
  },
  SET_USERID(state, id) {
    state.userId = id;
  },
  setLoader(state, bool) {
    state.loading = bool;
  },
};

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { req ,app }) {
    if (app.$auth.loggedIn) {
      const userToken = await app.$auth.strategies.keycloak.token.get();
      // const userToken = app.$auth.getToken("keycloak").split(" ")[1];
      const {
        realm_access: { roles: userRoles },
      } = jwtDecode(userToken);
      await commit("SET_USERID", jwtDecode(userToken).sub);
      await commit("SET_ALLOWED_PERMISSIONS", userRoles);
    }
  },
};

After user loggedIn Goes to the callback page and then goes to the login page. This is looping though.
